# Trying to make area in image clickable

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a contact page design with a 'Home' link inside a box.

The box is slightly hidden by wavy lines on top of it:

[image: Page with Home link box]

I tried two approaches to make the Home link clickable:

1) Create an href as a block element and place it with a z-index lower than that of the wavy lines. This prevents the link from being clickable.

2) Keep the Home box as part of the image, and place an href on top of it using CSS. This works only for certain browser widths, i.e. responsiveness is a problem.

```
a.home-link {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 width: 97px;
 height: 51px;
 left: 23vw;
 top: 10vw;
}
```

What's a more reliable way of achieving this?

Comment: Go with #2, use absolute positioning and adjust the position as needed with media queries as the size changes.

Comment: I've just posted the CSS I used in #2

Comment: Image maps will do your work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check into using [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/mBJq6/2/)**

```
.cover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:25px;
    opacity 0.9;
    pointer-events: none;/* <---relevant bit */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(mix of example 1 and 2)you could create an extra div with a higher z value and make it invisible so instead of clicking on home you click on an area above the home

a.k.a. a non-malicous form of this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking

Answer (score 0):

Catch a click on a page - every event bubbles up to the document level. Check the coordinates of the cursor. See if the coordinates are within the range of a Home tab. If they are, do whatever a click on Home tab is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Image maps, as they make a image CLICKABLE:

```
<img src="main.jpeg" width="1000" height="700" alt="image not displayed" usemap="#main">

<map name="main">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,120,40" href="home.htm" alt="Sun">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,130,40,250" href="about.htm" alt="Mercury">
</map>
```

Comment: I want this to be responsive.